# Is there a way to encrypt iBeacon UUID transmission?

Tags: android, encryption, uuid, ibeacon

I would like to develop an Android app that could automatically open a door (running in background)  once the person running my app is near to an iBeacon corresponding to my door.

My problem is the following: since iBeacon's parameters (UUID,Minor and Major) can be seen by other users as they are public, a malicious user could clone my beacon's parameter and act as my iBeacon, causing my app to trigger the door opening even if the user with my app is not physically near a door.

Is there a way to encrypt iBeacon UUID transmission? Or to guarantee that the beacon I see is truly mine?

Comment: I was on the understanding the iBeacon was an Apple specific technology, they recently cracked down on Android with it.

Answer (score 1):

I found two sources, one discusses the security problems with [opening doors withoutusing a physical key](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/332.pdf) and one [pretty funny treasure hunt](http://makezine.com/2014/01/03/hacking-the-ces-scavenger-hunt/) with iBeacons.

In short: To securely open your car when you are near there are multiple factors checked, none of them are available on your everyday iBeacon. Estimote Beacons use a kind of pseudorandomly changing UUID to prevent attackers from spoofing the UUID like the "winner" of the treasure hunt but it is still possible to relay them over a mobile network. Cars analyse timings to prevent this but need a two-way communication and a secure identity.